# Socks5 Proxy Configuration in Selenium Firefox driver

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, proxy

I'm trying to use proxy in selenium by this way:

```
firefox_options.add_argument('--proxy-server=socks5://' + 'username:pwd:addr@ipvanish.com:port')
```

I'm using ipvanish's proxies
there are some hostnames which I don't know where to put
Can someone please show me how can I configure a proxy properly, if possible, without using any extension? I searched and found some ways, though I was not able to comprehend the method yet so I'd appreciate it if you'd explain it explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `user:pass` authentication then you have to use [Proxy Auto Auth](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/proxy-auto-auth/ggmdpepbjljkkkdaklfihhngmmgmpggp?hl=en) extension for authentication.

Use [Crx downloader](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ajkhmmldknmfjnmeedkbkkojgobmljda) extension for downloading extension as a zip file.

Then you can load the Proxy Auto Auth extension in the selenium browser.

For Python

```
import os
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

executable_path = "path_to_webdriver"
os.environ["webdriver.chrome.driver"] = executable_path
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_extension('path_to_extension')
chrome_options.add_argument('--proxy-server=socks5://' + 'addr@ipvanish.com:port')
driver=webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=executable_path,chrome_options=chrome_options)
driver.get("http://stackoverflow.com")
driver.quit()
```

Path to extension is the path to a folder containing `manifest.json` file of the extension
Then you can simply use the code auth the proxy following the below code

```
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(@"chrome-extension://extensionName/options.html");
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.Id("login"))).Clear();
wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.Id("login"))).SendKeys("username");
wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.Id("password"))).Clear();
wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.Id("password"))).SendKeys("pwd");
wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.Id("retry"))).Clear();
wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.Id("retry"))).SendKeys("5");
wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.Id("save"))).Click();
```

This code for C# I hope you can translate for python.

Also, you can extract the downloaded Zip file of the extension and load it in the browser from the folder.